# how to delete COMMON files in source and destination via rsync

Tags: rsync

Help!!! I mistakenly rsynced the source folder into the wrong folder, and now I don't know which files were from the `rsync` and which were there initially. Is it possible to use `rsync` to delete ***in the destination folder*** the **common** files between the source and the destination folders? As far as I know all `--delete` tags are for deleting files that are in the destination but *not* in the source. What I want is to delete files in the destination folder that are *also* in the source folder.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: The source directory is Ubuntu, the target directory is technically on Windows, but I use the Ubuntu on Windows shell to do the rsync.